# Remoting Error: Requested Service Not Found

Tags: c#, remoting

I am trying to create a very simple example of remoting which isn't working. I start the host and when I start client, it says "requested service not found"

Parts of My Application are:

1. Remoting Object : MarshalByRefObject
2. ComponentHost
3. Client

It has been 2 days and I am going crazy. Requested if someone can tell that where am I wrong?

Comment: Remoting is only useful for cross-appdomain comms nowadays.  If you're still going crazy switch over to WCF.

Comment: Sometimes a simple spelling mistake in the url can this _RemotingException: Requested Service not found_  error.

Answer (score 1):

Questions in SO normally contain a summary of the code that poses problem, not a link to a complete project.

As you're new, I have taken a look anyway.

I could reproduce the problem, but not being a .NET remoting expert, I do not know what should be fixed in the  part of the config. An internet search returns a lot of samples that use the  tag for registration.

If you replace your client config by:

```
        <client>
            <wellknown
            type="MyRemoteObject.Greetings,MyRemoteObject"
            url="tcp://localhost:8737/ComponentHost" />
        </client>
```

and the server config by:

```
  <service>
      <wellknown
      mode="Singleton"
      type="MyRemoteObject.Greetings,MyRemoteObject"
      objectUri="ComponentHost"/>
  </service>
```

It works fine.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But this would make my instance singleton where as I wanted it to be clientActivated.

I did manage to resolve the issue with hit-and-trials by modifying client app.config from:

<client url="tcp://localhost:8000/ComponentHost">  to 

<client url="tcp://localhost:8000/">

Which resolved the issue. But in all samples I have read that applicationName as mentioned in App.config of server should be appended to URL in client's app.config.

I didn't get how it got fixed and eager to know the logic behind this fix.
Please help in understanding this!